# How to handle multi-domain user in ldap

Tags: ldap, authentication, authorization

I have an LDAP I have to create from scratch.
This will handle multiple domains, in which will be multiple apps. With multiple authorization based on each apps.

I don't want to duplicate users, and as I learned, a user cannot exist on multiple OU.
So I want a user to be able to access some app on some domain, and some other app on some other domain.
What would be the best way to model that?

I thought about : `cn=UserXYZ,ou=people,c=multiverse` for 1 user
and `cn=app1,dc=domain,dc=com,c=multiverse` for 1 app. And then handle each access right in each app, referencing the user from the people,multiverse.

Am I doing something crazy that wouldn't work? What is the correct way to do?
(the domain won't all be from `.com`)

Comment: Don't  know your exact requirement but instead increasing complexity of LDAP you can manage user privileges at application level using role base mechanism.

Comment: Yes, that was the plan.
My problem is that I want the users only in 1 OU, and I guess, closer to the root as possible. But is a root not being a `dc=` is possible?
I tried with c=multiverse and try to identify with `cn=admin,c=multiverse` and it doesn't work. So I guess I'm lacking basic LDAP knowledge that I can't seem to grasp/grok.